# Django: How to ensure a parent class only has one child instance

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

This a theoretical question which I want to reapply to my own study. However, say I have three models:

```py
class Person(models.Model)
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Teacher(Person)
   teacher_id = models.IntegerField()

class Student(Person)
   student_id = models.IntegerField()
```

What database/model restrictions can I put in place to ensure that an instance from both children cannot be created with the same `Person` parent.

Also, probably haven’t used the best example but assume `Person` can be created explicitly also.

> ***Note:** Obviously I could put a small check when saving but was hoping for something more "Pythonic"*

**Update (Further Definition)**

> Note: This is just to demonstrate that children can share the same parent.

Lets say we have a `Person`.

```py
>>> person = Person.objects.create(first_name="Joe", last_name="Bloggs")
>>> person
<Person: Person object (1)>
```

And we create a `Student`.

```py
>>> student = Student.objects.create(first_name="Joe", last_name="Bloggs", student_id=1234)
>>> student
<Student: Student object (1)>
```

And also create a `Teacher`

```
>>> teacher = Teacher.objects.create(first_name="Joe", last_name="Bloggs", teacher_id=12)                                           
>>> teacher                 
<Teacher: Teacher object (1)>
```

I can assign both the teacher and student to the person instance. Like so:

```
>>> person.teacher = teacher
>>> person.student = student
>>> person.student
<Student: Student object (7)>
>>> person.teacher
<Teacher: Teacher object (7)>
```

In some cases a `Student` may also be a `Teacher`. However, in my particular scenario a `Person` in  cannot be both a `Student` and a `Teacher`.

Comment: @Sumithran between where? I have no other models/relationships.

Comment: From teacher to person, Student to Person and so on

Answer (score 1):

As you described the models above, you don't have to add explicit restriction
to check if *an instance from both children cannot be created with the same `Person` parent.*

**Because :** `Teacher` and `Student` are also **Person** objects.
It's the multi table inheritance.

**Let's test it**

```
from app_name.models import Person, Teacher, Student

p1 = Person.objects.create(first_name='name1', last_name='name2')
p1.id
# output -> 1

t1 = Teacher.objects.create(first_name='name1', last_name='name2', teacher_id=1)
t1.id
# output -> 2 (The previous person id + 1)

s1 = Student.objects.create(first_name='name1', last_name='name2', student_id=1)
s1.id
# output -> 3 (The previous person, because student is a person 2 + 1 = 3)
```

As you can see all Person child are different `Pk`. Because all are the same `Person object`